# Function which can support to find the summed data which lead to summed value

Tags: excel, solver

I have a raw data of values, and **i have an certain amount it's sum of some of these values**, is there any function or solution can find what's the value needed to be summed in order **to get this number**.  for example (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)  this is the raw data and i have 12 as summation, i need to find which of these data can be lead to this summation from the raw data solution here is easy for example 1,2,3,6 or 3,4,5 etc..

for example (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)  this is the raw data and i have 12 as summation, i need to find which of these data can be lead to this summation from the raw data solution here is easy for example 1,2,3,6 or 3,4,5 etc..

Comment: That can be set up using the Solver and binary with sumproduct().

Comment: *i need to find which of these data can be lead to this summation* If you need to find **ALL** possible cobinations you need a pretty hard macro for that. Not possible with Excel only. But as the prior comment says, Solver can get a **single** solution at least.

Comment: What did you try? This is quite a large task to program.

Answer (score 0):

So, sheet and solver shown:

[image]

The use of binary for the changing values makes it easy.